# Using BatchNorm in PyTorch gives a significantly low accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, batch-normalization

I am working on an image classification problem on a Custom Dataset consisting of `1888`training images and `800` validation images(8 classes). I have tried applying transfer learning using various models from the `torchvision.models` library. For each model, I am using pre-trained weights and am only training the final `Linear` layer which performs classification. I have the following results so far on my validation set(using `batch size 32` and using `SGD with momentum` as the optimizer with `lr 0.001`)

```
1. Alexnet - 93 
2. VGG16 - 93  
3. VGG16_bn - 57 
4. Resnet50 - 26
5. VGG19 - 91
6. VGG19_bn - 59
```

I have repeated the experiments with both `model.train()` and `model.eval()` but the results do not seem to change much. So, from the results, I am guessing that the models having `BatchNorm` layers are performing very poorly compared to other models that don't have them. Any ideas why this might be happening? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I have looked at [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/model-eval-gives-incorrect-loss-for-model-with-batchnorm-layers/7561/3?u=jitesh) post on the forums about a possible solution which involves increasing the momentum value in the BatchNorm constructor.
How exactly am I supposed to make this change? Do I have to manually change the `batchnorm.py` code or is there any better way to make this happen?

Comment: Just making sure but you should be training in `.train` and validating using `.eval`, this is very important for batch norm in particular. Also, did you remove the dropout layers from your batch norm models? Batch norm and dropout don't play nicely together since dropout will cause the running batch norm statistics to be wrong.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the long delay. I tried using both `model.train()` and `model.eval`. None of it significantly improved the accuracy. There were no dropout layers in the model. I verified this by printing the model